# Send Push Notification on condition in One Signal

Tags: node.js, xamarin.forms, push-notification, onesignal

How to create a personalized push notification for users based on condition. I have implemented push notification with One Signal where I can send notifications to all the users about the stock market. I want to take this one step further by implementing something like in the image

[image: Push Notification based on condition]

In this, User can enter the price and if the price goes more than or less than the given price by a user then send a push notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case,you should use Server RestApi to create a notification.Make a request after determining the price like :

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

var request = WebRequest.Create("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications") as HttpWebRequest;

request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{"
                                    + "\"app_id\": \"5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c\","
                                    + "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"English Message\"},"
                                    + "\"include_player_ids\": [\"6392d91a-b206-4b7b-a620-cd68e32c3a76\",\"76ece62b-bcfe-468c-8a78-839aeaa8c5fa\",\"8e0f21fa-9a5a-4ae7-a9a6-ca1f24294b86\"]}");

string responseContent = null;

try {
   using (var writer = request.GetRequestStream()) {
    writer.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }

using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
        responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
  }
}
catch (WebException ex) {
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
}

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseContent);
```

For more information you could look at the onesigna official documentation,google **OneSigna**  > **Documentation** > **SERVER REST API** > **Create notification**